# drums_rnn_generate：command not found

Tags: tensorflow, magenta

when I tried to use magenta models——"[Drums RNN](https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/tree/master/magenta/models/drums_rnn)" to generate my drum tracks, I got this info:

```
drums_rnn_generate: command not found
```

and here is my .sh file

```
BUNDLE_PATH='/root/magenta/model/drum_kit_rnn.mag'
CONFIG='drum_kit'

drums_rnn_generate \
--config=${CONFIG} \
--bundle_file=${BUNDLE_PATH} \
--output_dir=/root/magenta/drums_rnn/generated \
--num_outputs=10 \
--num_steps=128 \
--primer_drums="[(36,)]"
```

I have installed magenta environment successfully,and activated magenta. it's strange that I can use command `melody_rnn_generate` which is from "[melody_rnn](https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/tree/master/magenta/models/melody_rnn)" without any problem.
Does someone get the same problem like mine?I want to know where the problem is and how to sovle it.Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you build with bazel?